# JavaScript filter non-digits on paste event in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, clipboarddata

I have an `<input type="number" />` and I want to prevent any non-numeric characters from being entered.

```
<input id="app-client-id" type="number" pattern="[0-9]+" />
```

For preventing regular keypresses, this can be done with

```js
const validKeys = new Set([
    'home',
    'end',
    'pageup',
    'pagedown',
    'delete',
    'backspace',
    'arrowleft',
    'arrowright',
]);

function isValidKeypress(e) {
    // numeric characters
    if (e.charCode >= 48 && e.charCode <= 57) {
        return true;
    }

    if (e.key && validKeys.has(e.key.toLowerCase())) {
        return true;
    }

    // for allowing select all, copy, and paste
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

$('#app-client-id').on('keypress', isValidKeypress);
```

Now all that's left is preventing pasting non-numeric characters, or ideally, filtering out non-numeric characters.

```js
function filterPastedText(e) {
    let clipboardData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData,
        text = clipboardData.getData('text').replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
    clipboardData.setData('text', text);
}

$('#app-client-id').on('paste', filterPastedText);
```

<s>This works in Chrome/Webkit.</s>  In Firefox, however, it throws an error on `setData()`:

> NoModificationAllowedError: Modifications are not allowed for this document

Any ideas on how to tell the browser to allow calling `setData()`?

If such a method does not exist, is there a way to manually "paste" the filtered value into the `input` at the right cursor position (and replacing selected text, if there is any) *without using a hidden `textarea`*?  I'm having trouble detecting the position of the cursor in an `input` element, regardless of whether text is selected; `myInput.selectionStart` is always `null`.

#### Edit

It turns out calling `setData()` does not, in fact, work in Chrome.  Setting the type to `number` automatically filtered out non-numeric characters *except* 'e', '-', and '.', and the string I was testing it on, did not include any of those characters.  Calling `setData()` simply fails silently.

Comment: I've got not an answer, but another puzzle for you: I started playing around with filtering out non-numeric input myself, and found out that on my Mac, I couldn't filter out accented characters like `é` anyway but checking after an `oninput` event. There's never even a `keypress` event corresponding to the character being entered.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you can take is to simply allow unwanted characters to momentarily enter the input field, but monitor `oninput` events, check the value of the input field for the unwanted characters at each event, and if any are found, update the input field with a filtered version of its value.

**Update:**

I've discovered that, ironically, it's harder to limit keyboard input to digits when you create an `input` as `type="number"` rather than `type="text"`. Why? Because when you use `type="number"` non-numeric input can still slip by, but you don't get to see those characters in the value of the input field -- the value is either a valid number, or it's an empty string. That gives you no opportunity to filter the input and keep the valid digits that might be there.

I've created a Plunker with the current state of my own attempts to limit a text field to numeric input: http://plnkr.co/edit/xsVQG1EzsDLMt8POCJUX?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, that's my temporary workaround.  I'd like to find a cleaner solution, if possible, because I'm a perfectionist. ;)

Comment: I suspect messing around with the clipboard is being treated as a security threat, so you might not find a workaround for this if that's the case.

Comment: I've updated my answer after a bit more research and experimentation.

Comment: @kshetline Is your code in a state where you'd be happy to incorporate it into this answer?