# asp.net : Only 10 digits numbers in textbox

Tags: asp.net, regex

Issue : how to restrict textbox to only allow 10 digits using type = number and hide the arrow on a aspx file
**Requirements:**

- no more than 10 digits in the box
- allows copy and paste but filters out letters in it for eg 1234a or a1234
- allows only numbers

```js
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" IsReadOnly="false" Type="Number" Maxlength="10" ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpression1" runat="server" ControValidator="txt" ValidationExpression="\d+" ErrorMessage="only numeric values allowed."></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Have you tried `ControlToValidate="txt" ValidationExpression="\d{,10}"`?

Comment: without Type = Number , validationExpression = "\d{,10}" works .
But it does NOT resolve all the listed requirements:
-no letters allowed
-only numbers up to 10 digits
-should allow copy and paste

Here are all the options that I have tried :
- \d+$
- pattern = "[0-9]{10}"

Comment: Are you saying that you want it to only allow digits to be *entered*? If so: [asp.net validation to make sure textbox has integer values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18458933/1115360). If you also want to prevent pasting in non-digits, I'm sure you can do some research for that.

Comment: Thank you so much . The above solution , does not allow letter input but allows letters if it is copy and paste. 
it should filter out a letter in the instance of a copy paste.

Comment: You could try using `TextMode` instead of `Type`: [Render ASP.NET TextBox as HTML5 Input type "Number"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49859912/1115360), but it might not make any difference.

Comment: There's [this incomplete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50092356/1115360) to deal with the paste issue. It may be simpler to just tell the user that the input data is invalid and what is required: the user should soon tire of trying to enter incorrect data.

Comment: TextMode did the same thing Type did , no 10 digit restriction .

Comment: the warning sign shows but just knowing users will still search which spits out a yellow box which is what I am trying to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  
            TextMode="Number" Width="187px"
            onkeypress="return this.value.length<=10" >
        </asp:TextBox>
```

If you need to hide the up/down (spinner), then use this:

```
<style>

  .myspinhide 
  /* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
  input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
  input::-webkit-inner-spin-button 
  {-webkit-appearance: none; margin: 0;}

   /* Firefox */
   .myspinhide input[type=number] {-moz-appearance: textfield;} 
</style>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  CssClass="myspinhide"
            TextMode="Number" Width="236px"
            onkeypress="return this.value.length<=10"  >
        </asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is worked as well

```js
<asp TextBox ID="txtId" width = "205px" runat="server" MaxLength="10"/>
<asp:RangeValidator runat="server" ID = "valRangeTxtcontactId" controlToValidate="txtId" Type ="Integer" Minimumvalue = "0" Maximumvalue ="2147483647" CssClass="input-error" ErrorMessage="Integers only" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RangeValidator>
```